# more than 100 items through batchGetItem in dynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

If you request more than 100 items, BatchGetItem returns a ValidationException with the message "Too many items requested for the BatchGetItem call."
Is there any way  to process more than 100 items in dynamoDB through batchGetItems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With a single `BatchGetItem` request the maximum number of items to get is 100, as [documented by AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html):

> A single operation can retrieve up to 16 MB of data, which can contain as many as 100 items.
>
> […]
>
> **Important**
>
> If you request more than 100 items, BatchGetItem returns a ValidationException with the message "Too many items requested for the BatchGetItem call."

There is also no pagination available as it is for actions like [`Query`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html). What you could do is to implement pagination yourself so you make one `BatchGetItem` request per 100 items. If you go down this route, you should also make sure to properly handle the `UnprocessedKeys`.

While it's not clear what your use case for fetching more than 100 items at once from DynamoDB is, your problem could be a sign for a poor DynamoDB schema design. Depending on your use case redesigning your schema and/or using an action like `Query` might be a better choice.