# Is there a way to get more than 100 items from DynamoDB using a single BatchGetItem?

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

Currently I cannot find any docs regarding how to achieve this without creating your own recursion to split the array of keys into chunks and call `BatchGetItem` for each chunk.

Is there a more efficient way? to do this all in parallel

Thanks

Comment: You can't do it with a single query. This is like this so AWS can meet their SLAs.

Comment: How many the best way to batch? I am thinking chunks of 100

Comment: Does this answer your question? [more than 100 items through batchGetItem in dynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59907500/more-than-100-items-through-batchgetitem-in-dynamodb)

Answer (score 0):

BatchGetItems can only return up to 100 items, this is a hard limit.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchGetItem.html

However, if those items share the same partition key but different sort key you can return more than 100, you would be able to get up to 1MB worth of data.